# Validate or Override FluentNhibernate Database to Enum mapping

Tags: c#, .net, enums, fluent-nhibernate

I have a database which is accessed by multiple systems. Ours reads a table using Fluent Nhibernate and Automapping.

One of the columns is a string representing an enum. In most installations this is fine, but every now and then another system will persist an invalid value. How can I catch these invalid values and either convert or ignore them?

Example:

```
Database Table:
ID  MyEnum
0   "One"
1   "Two"
2   "Invalid"

MyEnum
{
  One,
  Two
}
```

I'm already using `IAutoMappingOverride` with my model, is there anyway to pass a function to the mapper to do validation/conversion (say I wanted to convert any unknowns to `MyEnum.One`)?
Or is there a simpler way that I'm missing?

Where I got to was using a combination of [@Firo's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19354181/1811110) and the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5411075/1811110) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3263890/1811110)

```
class SafeEnumType<T> : ImmutableUserType where T : struct
{
    public override object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        T value;
        if (Enum.TryParse((string)rs[names[0]], out value))
            return value;
        else
            return default(T);
    }

    public override void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, value.ToString(), index);
    }

    public override Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(T); }
    }

    public override SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { SqlTypeFactory.GetString(100) }; }
    }
}
```

and adding

```
mapping.Map(x => x.Type).CustomType(typeof(SafeEnumType<EventType>));
```

to my `AutomapOverride.Override()` fn

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In NHibernate there is IUserType which lets you define custom conversion code. [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7484139/671619) is a base class of mine which you can use because enums are immutable types

code

```
class SpecialEnumUserType : ImmutableUserType
{
    public override object NullSafeGet(IDataReader rs, string[] names, object owner)
    {
        TheSpecialEnum value;
        if (Enum.TryParse<TheSpecialEnum>((string)rs[names[0]], out value))
            return value;
        else
            return default(TheSpecialEnum);
    }

    public override void NullSafeSet(IDbCommand cmd, object value, int index)
    {
        NHibernateUtil.String.NullSafeSet(cmd, value.ToString(), index);
    }

    public override Type ReturnedType
    {
        get { return typeof(TheSpecialEnum); }
    }

    public override SqlType[] SqlTypes
    {
        get { return new[] { SqlTypeFactory.GetString(50) }; }
    }
}
```

and convention to apply them to every enum property

```
class EnumHandlingConvention : IPropertyConvention
{
    public void Apply(IPropertyInstance instance)
    {
        if (instance.Type == typeof(TheSpecialEnum))
        {
            instance.CustomType<SpecialEnumUserType>();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: OK, it's not very neat for my purposes, though. Is there an easier way to intercept the DB to object step for a particular property?

Comment: that is the easiest way. What's your exact problem with the IUserType?

Comment: specifically wanted to only handle one particular enum, if you edit your answer I'll accept it, thx.

Comment: changed all occurences to the special enum